# CSS Toggle Anchor from url

Tags: javascript, html, css, anchor, show

I have 3 sections in my webpage that are become visible or invisible when clicked (this is done using CSS).

I then have these 3 sections linkable from the nav bar using anchor points (on the page the anchor tag has the class of 'togg'), when I click a link it goes to the right section, but I need the relevant section to become visible as well.

Ive searched possible answers on this site and from those and have bodged what I thought would work:

I currently have a call to a javascript function called 'hasher' in body onload.

The function then says

```
    function hasher()
    {
        if(!window.location.hash)
        {
           return;
        }
        else
        {
           var hasher = unescape(window.location.hash.substring(1));
           $('a.togg[href=#"' + hasher + '"]').click();
    }
```

But this doesnt seem to work and my knowledge of Javascript is not such that I can work out where to go from here.

Please can someone help! Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: I fixed it!  ta - it just needed to say $("#" + hasher).click();

Answer (score 0):

if `hasher` is the id of the section element needed to be visible use

html

```
<div class="section" id="something"></div>
<div class="section" id="something1"></div>
<div class="section" id="something2"></div>
```

js

```
$('a.togg[href=#"' + hasher + '"]').click();
$(".section").not("#"+hasher").hide(); //Hides all sections except the one that has id in hasher
$('#'+hasher).show(); //shows the section with id in hasher
```